# The value of "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead" setting?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

The value of `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` in a Spark job with YARN should be allocated to App or just the max value?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead
```

Is just the max value .The goal is to calculate OVERHEAD as a percentage of real executor memory, as used by RDDs and DataFrames

```
--executor-memory/spark.executor.memory
```

controls the executor heap size, but JVMs can also use some memory off heap, for example for interned Strings and direct byte buffers.

The value of the `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`
property is added to the executor memory to determine the full memory request to YARN for each executor. It defaults to max(executorMemory * 0.10, with minimum of 384).

The executors will use a memory allocation based on the property of `spark.executor.memory`plus an overhead defined by `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I still wondering ,I have applied memory from yarn for my job  then I set the value of 'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', does it means  it will add extra memory for my job?

Comment: By default, spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead is AM memory * 0.10, with a minimum of 384. This means that if we set spark.yarn.am.memory to 777M, the actual AM container size would be 2G. This is because 777+Max(384, 777 * 0.10) = 777+384 = 1161, and the default yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=1024, so 2GB container will be allocated to AM.