# PySpark job to fetch hive table is breacking

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

while trying to run hive query pyspark giving following error

**spark code**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
# Create a spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("app name").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
query = "some query"
df = spark.sql(query)
df.show()
```

I am getting exception as below:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o268.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 150 in stage 65.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 150.3 in stage 65.0 (TID 54677, phyrhc105d4-prd, executor 4431): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4431 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_e103_1575680207115_1732381_01_004463 on host: phyrhc105d4-prd. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
```

**error log**

```
Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3106d06b6e49> in <module>()
----> 1 df.show()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in show(self, n, truncate)
    334         """
    335         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 336             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
    337         else:
    338             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate)))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o268.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 150 in stage 65.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 150.3 in stage 65.0 (TID 54677, phyrhc105d4-prd, executor 4431): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4431 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_e103_1575680207115_1732381_01_004463 on host: phyrhc105d4-prd. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: the error is probably in the query not in the show. One of the stages of executing the query fails. This is either due to cluster problems or the query itself has problems

Comment: @Paul how to fix cluster problem

Comment: How did you start pyspark? Have you used any memory options? Did you use `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`?

Comment: Can you check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/41057311/1305344